# Current mode vs Voltage mode signal conditioning

Tags: sensor, noise, signal-processing

I am working in sensor design and would like to compare the signal conditioning of current output sensors vs voltage output sensors about advantages and disadvantages of each.

Can some one point out some sources such as books or papers where can I find these information?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

http://usa.balluff.com/OTPDF/020_BB_Analog-Signals_Current-vs-Voltage.pdf

Here is a short article with pros and cons for voltage and current signals from sensors.

In genereral voltage signals are for cheap stuff nearby.

And current signals are for cases where sensor itself needs current, or wires are long, or noise is important.